# bash script - flatten directory structure

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am looking for a shell script that would flatten a given directory structure but ONLY if there is only 1 subfolder in that directory. For instance: the script would flatten this folder:

```
/folder
    /subfolder
        file1
        file2
```

into:

```
/folder
    file1
    file2
```

but would skip (do nothing) this folder

```
/folder
    /subfolder1
    /subfolder2
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Steve

Comment: I've fixed the markup and formatting of the text of the question. Please modify if I got it wrong.

Comment: This would involve rebuilding relative symlinks, I gather.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat naive approach:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for dir do

    # get list of directories under the directory $dir
    set -- "$dir"/*/

    # if there are more than one, continue with the next directory
    # also continue if we didn't match anything useful
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ] || [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # the pathname of the subdirectory is now in $1

    # move everything from beneath the subdirectory to $dir
    # (this will skip hidden files)
    mv "$1"/* "$dir"

    # remove the subdirectory
    # (this will fail if there were hidden files)
    rmdir "$1"

done
```

Using `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for dir do

    # get list of directories under the directory $dir
    subdirs=( "$dir"/*/ )

    # if there are more than one, continue with the next directory
    # also continue if we didn't match anything useful
    if [ "${#subdirs[@]}" -gt 1 ] || [ ! -d "${subdirs[0]}" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # the pathname of the subdirectory is now in ${subdirs[0]}

    # move everything from beneath the subdirectory to $dir
    # (this will skip hidden files)
    mv "{subdirs[0]}"/* "$dir"

    # remove the subdirectory
    # (this will fail if there were hidden files)
    rmdir "${subdirs[0]}"

done
```

Both scripts would be run as

```
$ ./script.sh dir1 dir2 dir3
```

or

```
$ ./script.sh */
```

to run it across all directories in the current directory.

Apart from the caveats in the code, this would also fail to relink symbolic links.  To do that, you would have to go through all possible locations in the filesystem and look for links pointing into the subdirectory under `/folder` and recreate them so that they point to the correct new place.  I will not write the code far that here.

Also, no check is made when moving things out of the subdirectory to make sure that there are no entries with the same names already existing under `/folder`.

Comment: Thank you. Ill give it a try.  How about if I wanted to check all folders in any given directory in a loop like in "for every folder in directory do ...."?

Comment: @StevenD You wanted to do this only when the directory contained a _single_ subdirectory, right?  A loop would not allow you to count the number of subdirectories.

Comment: @StevenD Or I might have misunderstood you... Do you mean that you want to iterate over a number of folders, and flatten each individually if _they_ contained only one directory? I.e. let `/folder` (in your question) be dynamic?

Comment: Kusalanda. Exactly.  Flatten each folder (within a directory) that contains only one subfolder. Doable?

Comment: @StevenD See updated answer. Basically we do the operation on each directory listed on the command line of the script.

Comment: I tried both scripts - they exit with no error messages yet no changes are performed to any directories?

Comment: @StevenD Do the directories given on the command line contain only a single subdirectory?

Comment: Kusalanda.  No. They contain multiple subdirectories.  What I am trying to do to run this script on an entire flash drive containing multiple directories with folders (music files .m4a) so no hidden files and no symlinks. Music files are organized like this: Genre/Artists/Albums